# Safely execute script coming from user input in Python

Tags: python, parsing, security, exec

I'm looking for a safe mechanism in Python to execute potentially unsafe script code coming from a user.

Code example:

```
def public(v):
    print('Allowed to trigger this with '+v)
    
def secret():
    print('Not allowed to trigger this')
    

unsafe_user_code = '''
def user_function(a):
    if 'o' in a:
        public('parameter')

a = 'hello'
user_function(a)
'''

run_code(unsafe_user_code, allowed=['public'])
```

This could be easily achieved with `exec()` but as I understand there is no way of using `exec()` in a safe way in Python.

Here are my requirements:

1. The syntax of the script should ideally be similar to Python (but could also be something like JavaScript)
2. Standard mechanisms like string operations, if/else/while and definition of own variables and functions need to be available in the script
3. The script should only be able to execute certain functions (in the example, only `public()` would be allowed)
4. I would like to rely on Python-based implementations/libraries only as I don't want to have dependencies on Python-external software
5. It should not introduce a security risk

The only way I found so far is to use a parsing library, where I would have to define everything by myself (e.g. this one: https://github.com/lark-parser/lark ).

Is there a better way to achieve something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

Here's the full python file if you want to copy:

```py
from copy import copy

def public(v):
    print('Allowed to trigger this with '+v)
    
def secret():
    print('Not allowed to trigger this')
    

unsafe_user_code = '''
def user_function(a):
    if 'o' in a:
        public('parameter')
        # secret()
        # If you uncomment it, it'll throw an error saying 'secret' does not exist

a = 'hello'
user_function(a)
'''

def run_code(code_to_run,allowed:list[str]):
    g = globals()
    allowed_dict = {f"{name}": g[name] for name in allowed}
    code = compile(code_to_run,'','exec')
    
    def useless():
        pass
    
    useless.__code__ = code
    
    g = copy(useless.__globals__)
    for x in g:
        del useless.__globals__[x]
    for x in allowed_dict:
        useless.__globals__[x] = allowed_dict[x]
    
    useless()
    
run_code(unsafe_user_code, allowed=['public'])
```

### Explaination

I don't think you need a parsing library.
You can use one of python's [Built-in Functions](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in,) called [compile()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/compile).

You can compile code like this:

```py
    text_to_compile = "print('hello world')"
    code = compile(
      text_to_compile, # text to compile
      'file_name', # file name
      'exec' # compile mode
    )
```

[more about compile modes](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/compile)

and then you can run it simply by:

```py
    exec(code) # prints 'hello world' in the terminal
```

or, you can put that code inside of a function and run the function:

```py
    def useless():
        pass
    
    useless.__code__ = code
    useless() # prints 'hello world' in the terminal
```

now for changing the scope of the function, we can access its `__global__` dictionary and remove everything from it.
then we add the functions/variables that we want to it.

```py
# from copy import copy
def run_code(code_to_run,allowed:list[str]):
    g = globals()
    allowed_dict = {f"{name}": g[name] for name in allowed}
    code = compile(code_to_run,'','exec')
    
    def useless():
        pass
    
    useless.__code__ = code
    
    g = copy(useless.__globals__)
    for x in g:
        del useless.__globals__[x]
    for x in allowed_dict:
        useless.__globals__[x] = allowed_dict[x]
    
    useless()
```

alright let's talk about what's happening:

```py
   def run_code(code_to_run,allowed:list[str]):
```

the `:list[str]` is just defining the type of the variable `allowed`.

```py
    g = globals()
```

using the `globals()` method we are able to get all of the variables that the function `run_code` has access to. this includes the public and the secret functions.

```py
    allowed_dict = {f"{name}": g[name] for name in allowed}
```

and use the variable names that you passed down into the `run_code` function and get the variables from the *globals* of this function.

the it's pretty much the same as saying:

```py
    allowed_dict = {}
    for name in allowed:
        allowed_dict[name] = g[name]
```

alright then we compile the code.
we also make a `useless` function and put the compiled code into the function:

```py
    code = compile(code_to_run,'','exec')
    
    def useless():
        pass
    
    useless.__code__ = code
```

after that, we copy the globals of the `useless` function:

```py
    g = copy(useless.__globals__)
```

we copy the globals in the function so that later in the code we can loop over it and delete it.
we do this because we cannot delete something from a dictionary while a for loop is iterating it.

```py
    for x in g:
        del useless.__globals__[x]
```

we delete everything in the `useless` function's global.
the useless function is an empty function but it's global is filled with all sort of stuff, like the **public** and the **secret** functions.

and then we just put all the *allowed* variables into the globals of the function so that the code inside of the function can use the variables/functions.

```py
    for x in allowed_dict:
        useless.__globals__[x] = allowed_dict[x]
```

then we can just run the useless function:

```py
    useless()
```

and that's pretty much it all.